# SQL: Of the shortest 300 trips how many of these riders were kids

Tags: mysql, sql

Columns: duration, riders: men, women, null, kids.

```
SELECT duration, riders
FROM Table
ORDER BY duration ASC LIMIT 300
```

How count how many were kids riders of the shortest 300 trips? Shortest means shortest based on duration times.

Comment: The nature of kids, men, female columns is not clear. Add the full table DDL sentence

Comment: How to tell which trips where short? Is trip_times maybe trip_time, i.e. not the number of trips, but the duration?

Comment: What to do in case of ties? Say, three trips with the same duration at position 299, 300, and 301: Consider only 298? Or 301? Or pick two of the three trips arbitrarily to get exactly 300? Or to put it to an extreme, let's say there are 400 trips in your table, 200 lasted one hour and 200 lasted two hours. What are the "shortest 300 trips" then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the very limited information provided:

```
WITH SHORT_TRIPS AS (
SELECT trip_times, riders
FROM Table
ORDER BY trip_times ASC LIMIT 300
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SHORT_TRIPS
WHERE riders = 'kids'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(riders='kids'),0) FROM (
    SELECT trip_times, riders
    FROM Table
    ORDER BY trip_times ASC LIMIT 300 
) short_rides;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select trip_times, count(riders) from table 
where riders like 'kids' 
ORDER BY trip_times ASC LIMIT 300
```